# Returning two elements: Array vs. Struct

Tags: ruby

I have a method `calculate(data)` that returns two values. One is a grade (`Float`) and another is details `(Hash`). Comparing the following two options, is there a preferred way?

```
def calculate(data)
  ...
  [grade, details]
end

grade, details = calculate(data)
```

vs.

```
def calculate(data)
  ...
  Result.new(grade, details)
end

result = calculate(data)
grade = result.grade
details = result.details
```

What is more idiomatic in Ruby?

Comment: I generalized the title from "two" to "multiple". Why did you narrow it back to "two"? It is better to keep things as general as possible.

Comment: I think it can heavily influence the decision, hence I have tailored it to the 2-[tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array form is more idiomatic. In fact, you can do it via Ruby's built-in multiple returns mechanism:

```
def calculate(data)
  ...
  return grade, details
end

grade, details = calculate(data)
```

Comment: I don't think `return grade, details` is any better than `[grade, details]`.

Comment: @sawa but more idiomatic.

Comment: It is more idiomatic to omit `return` when possible.

Comment: My point was to illustrate that Ruby specifically permits for explicit return values which are packed into an array.

Comment: @sawa I agree, but that does not invalidate the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

For a method intended to be used internal to a library, your first option is more efficient and would be a good choice. For a method intended to be used by a user of a library, something along the lines of your second option has more desirable interface, and should be used.

Answer (score 3):

The best of both worlds:

```
Result = Struct.new(:grade, :details) do
  def to_ary; [grade, details] end
end

def calculate(data)
  Result.new(1, 'Two')
end

grade, details = calculate(:ignore)
# => #<struct Result grade=1, details="Two">

grade
# => 1

details
# => 'Two'
```

As an experiment, I once monkeypatched `Hash#each` to `yield` a `Struct.new(:key, :value)` instead of a two-element `Array` and pretty much all I had to do to get most of the RubySpecs passing again was to implement `to_ary`.

Comment: Structs can be splatted: `Result = Struct.new(:grade, :details); grade, details = *Result.new(1, 'Two')`